# DOI for JMLR papers

Tags: journals, doi

This is probably a beginner-level question but how do I obtain the `doi` for Journal of Machine Learning Research(JMLR) papers? Most of JMLR papers that I refer to seem to be missing a `doi`. For ex, if you go to this [page](http://jmlr.org/papers/v18/16-558.html), and look at the `bib` entry, there is no `doi` information. I know arXiv doesn't assign `doi`s, doesn't JMLR either?

Comment: Can you please elaborate - what does JMLR stand for? Journal of Machine Learning Research?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

arXiv doesn’t assign DOI’s because it’s for pre-prints which can be, and are frequently, updated, which would make this confusing.

Why the Journal of Machine Learning Research doesn’t is curious. They have a Q1 SJR rank and seem high quality having glimpsed through the latest articles in Volume 20. You’re right - I couldn’t see a DOI on any of them. I guess the journal just doesn’t habitually request a DOI for their articles. For those that do, perhaps the authors specifically requested it, or perhaps they were exceptional or special issues and warranted the DOI. I’m just speculating.

But it’s not mandatory and it’s not a problem. As long as you have the journal and volume number, that should be sufficient for a reference (along with author, year, title of course).